# Finding a line of approximation using the normal equations for $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, approximation, orthonormal

To find the line $y=ax+b$ that best approximates the data points $\{(-2,3),(0,5),(1,7)\}$ I need to use the equation

$$A\vec{x}=\vec{b}\ \ \ (\mbox{where}\ \vec{x}=\left({a\atop b}\right))$$

Then use the normal equation

$$A^TA\vec{x}=A^T\vec{b}\ \ \rightarrow\ \ \vec{x}=(A^TA)^{-1}(A^T\vec{b})$$

- **Given the points above how do I construct a matrix $A$ and a vector $\vec{b}$ ?**
- **Is there a name for this process of find an equation of a line ?**

Comment: This is called [the method of least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

Answer (score 3):

As John said in the comments, this method is known as Least Square Fitting. In this case, think of how matrix multiplication works, and consider the point $(c, d)$. You would have $cx + b = d$. So, in your question, the matrix $A$ would be 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
-2 & 1\\
0 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and your $\vec{b}$ would be the $y$-values.
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
3\\
5\\
7
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Afterwards, it is simple to solve $A^tA\vec{x} = A^t\vec{b}$ through Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the classical [least squares line fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29).

We want to minimize
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left|ax_i+b-y_i\right|^2\tag{1}
$$
To do this, we consider the varying $a$ and $b$ and look for stationary points:
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\sum_{i=1}^n\left|ax_i+b-y_i\right|^2\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^n\left(ax_i+b-y_i\right)x_i\\
\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i
&=a\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\sum_{i=1}^n\left|ax_i+b-y_i\right|^2\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^n\left(ax_i+b-y_i\right)\\
\sum_{i=1}^ny_i
&=a\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+bn\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we want to solve
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2&\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\\
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i&n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\\
\sum_{i=1}^ny_i
\end{bmatrix}\tag{4}
$$
for $a$ and $b$.

---

Note that if we write
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&1\\
x_2&1\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
x_n&1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\text{and}
\quad
\vec{b}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}
$$
then $(4)$ becomes
$$
A^TA\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=A^T\,\vec{b}\tag{6}
$$